How to register individual form field with react hook form and shad cn
So i'm trying to register a single field to my react hook form but it keeps throwing an error
this is my form which i abstract from useform()
const form = useForm({
resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
        values: initialData == null ? { ...defaultValues, creatorId: customerId || '', shopId: searchParamsValue ? searchParamsValue : '' } : undefined,
        defaultValues: initialData ? defaultValues : undefined,
})

and this is me trying to register a random field
form.register('subCategoryId', '32427236872ggeghsfwwsfsf');

and this is the error I'm getting
Argument of type '"32427236872ggeghsfwwsfsf"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RegisterOptions<{ name: string; images: string[]; sizes: string[]; colors: string[]; price: number; categoryId: string; shopId: string; creatorId: string; description: string; stock: number; subCategoryId?: string | undefined; discount?: number | undefined; negotiable?: boolean | undefined; isFeatured?: boolean | un...'

I believe the solution is to spread the form.register field but I'm just stumped at the moment. Please help me as I'm relatively new to nextJS

So, the error was coming from my use of the defaultValues and values on the zodResolver.
Apparently, default values and values cannot be undefined. So i just used a conditional to check for initial data and if it is set to true, I pass the intitial data to the form. If not, I pass the values of empty strings and booleans as the case applies.
Also, my useEffect on the first render was calling another render. Problem took me almost a day to debug but thank God, that is out of the way
